# Rails determine what caused a 404?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm seeing this in my production log:

```
INFO -- : Started GET "/404" for 178.167.132.245 at 2014-04-18 17:43:55 +0000
INFO -- : Processing by ErrorsController#not_found as */*
INFO -- :   Rendered errors/not_found.html within layouts/application (0.1ms)
INFO -- : Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And I'm seeing them a lot. I want to know what URL caused the 404, meaning, what was the initial URL that was typed that was not found, that caused the page to be rerouted to the 404 page. Is that possible?

Comment: It would be easier to determine the cause if you specified what version of Rails you're running, as the routing behavior changed drastically between 2.3 and 3.0, and then again with 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to add some logging instrumentation to ErrorsController#not_found that logs out request.fullpath, like this:

```
class Errors Controller < ApplicationController
  def not_found
    logger.info "Not Found: '#{request.fullpath}'.\n#{exception.class} error was raised for path .\n#{exception.message}"
    render status: 404
  end
end
```

That will give you both the path and the triggering exception (i.e., it might be `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`, or it might be `ActionController::RoutingError`) in your logs.

There's some really good discussion in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gonzedge/1563416)  as well.